# NatTable: How can you access column header of a particular column?

Tags: eclipse, nattable, nebula

In the example below,

```java
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER,
                new BeveledBorderDecorator(
                        new VerticalTextPainter(false, true, true)),
                DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER);
```

the column header text is vertically aligned, how can I apply this styling to a particular column instead of all columns, Looking for guidance.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure conditional styling via config labels. Have a look at our getting started tutorial to see how this can be done.

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#architecture_labels